# При запуске апплета из IntelliJ IDEA не отображаются русские буквы

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet

В IDEA стоит кодировка UTF-8, в консоли IDEA при вводе chcp выдает 866. если в IDEA меняю на Ansi-II то выводит вопросительные знаки а на UTF-8 какие то иероглифы.

Comment: перезагрузить и перезапустить пробовали?

Comment: да. третий день с этим мучаюсь

Comment: Попробуйте `chcp 65001` и если меняли шрифт, то поставьте "умолчательный"

Comment: Не помогает. Все Ровно в окне апплетов иероглифы. может при javac Main.java уже все превращается в иероглифы? я открыл файл Main.class там уже иероглифы вместо текста. а когда пишу на английскими буквами в файле Main.class норм показывает.

Answer (score 2):

Очень странное поведение.

Вот настройки

[image: Настройки]

Вот проект - кодировка utf8. Консоль - 866

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для компилятора никаких дополнительных опций не делалось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все буквы на месте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как Вы запускайте апплет? я создаваю applet.html файл и в командной строке пишу appletviewer applet.html. может я что то не так делаю. а в IE не запускается, ругается на безопасность .

Comment: Я запускаюсь в Idea - создал конфигрурацию запуска (3 скрин) и кнопка "зеленый треугольник".

А в 'applet.html' какая кодировка указана?

Comment: в applet.html так же UTF-8

Comment: получилось, спасибо! я конфигурацию не создавал)

Comment: У appletviewer  так же есть параметр `-encoding` по идее должен принять `utf-8`. Ну и `-Jfile.encoding=utf-8` как опцию. (http://www.mstu.edu.ru/study/materials/java/pril_1.htm) В вашем вопросе IDEA - лишнее звено как составляющая. Windows+cmd+appletviewer  правильный набор ключевых слов.